# GcmTaskService not working

Tags: java, android

I want to replace my BroadcastReceiver in my project to GcmNetworkManager. So I read some tutorials and do like that:
1) In manifest I add:

```
<service android:name=".WakeOnLanService"
      android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

2) Service:

```
public class WakeOnLanService extends GcmTaskService {

@Override
public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
    return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int i, int i1) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Выполнилось",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, i, i1);
}
}
```

3) Schedule in activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GcmNetworkManager mGcmNetworkManager = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this);
    Task task = new OneoffTask.Builder()
            .setService(WakeOnLanService.class)
            .setExecutionWindow(0, 2)
            .setTag("MyTag")
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .build();
    mGcmNetworkManager.schedule(task);
}
}
```

But it is not work, Toast not shown. How to do it correct and what is the best practice to run the Service with GcmNetworkManager on internet connect, like it was in Broadcast Receiver?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't run your code in `onStartCommand`.

Instead, use `onRunTask`.

```
@Override
public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Выполнилось",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
}
```

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager#run_tasks):

> When the scheduler starts your service, a new thread is created and
>   the system invokes onRunTask(). Implement the logic for your tasks by
>   overriding onRunTask();

As for running the task when a connection to the internet is established. It is better not to do that, unless you really need to. That is the point of this task. To schedule your tasks to work alongside other tasks. If you really need it to fire when an internet connection is established, you will need to use a BroadcastReceiver and run the code manually. You cannot fire this task at an arbitrary time.

Comment: If I will use Broadcast Receiver it will not work in android N

Comment: Why not? Can't you register for `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>`?

Comment: Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) do not receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they register to receive them in their manifest. Apps that are running can still listen for CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE on their main thread by registering a BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver().

Comment: Ah ha, good information. Then you will likely need to wait for the task to run. I don't immediately see anything else wrong. Try setting the `.setExecutionWindow(0, 2)` line to a time further into the future with a larger delay for testing, such as: `.setExecutionWindow(10, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

For those with some question about it, consider migrating to WorkManager:

```
public class UploadWorker extends Worker {

    public UploadWorker(
        @NonNull Context context,
        @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
      // Do the upload operation ...

      myUploadOperation()

      // Indicate whether the task finished successfully with the Result
      return Result.success()
    }
}


Constraints uploadConstraints = new Constraints.Builder()
    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
    .setRequiresCharging(true)
    .build();

OneTimeWorkRequest uploadTask =
        new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class)
  .setConstraints(uploadConstraints)
  .build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(uploadTask);
```

Reference:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/migrating-gcm